# Como resolver erro na configuração de URL no Django?

Tags: django, path, http-status-404

Estou começando a aprender django(ou tentando) mas não consigo resolver o seguinte problema:

> "Using the URLconf defined in SiteJG.urls, Django tried these URL
> patterns, in this order:
>
> Templates/main.html
>
> The empty path didn't match any of these."

**settings.py**:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'SiteJG.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('templates/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html'))
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não estou a perceber bem a ideia do que estas a fazer , mas na tua pasta do projeto tens que ter uma pasta a dizer templates, algo deste genero :

```
   ├── MEU PROJETO
   │   └── settings.py
   └── manage.py
   |___PASTA DA APP
   |
   └── templates
```

De seguida no `settings.py` terás que incluir a incluir a pasta :

```
 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Depois terás que ir a tua app , e terás um ficheiro `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

De seguida é so incluir esta view que criamos no `urls.py`

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
 ]
```